# Deploy Multiple branch on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Heroku application that already deploy on Heroku (master-branch) in that I created new branch staging. The staging branch code are totally different with master. Now I want to deploy staging on Heroku but that will not affect on master. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to created separate applications on Heroku for each environment that you need. I typically create dev and staging using the free tier.

Here is blog post that walks you through the process:
http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/how-to-create-a-staging-environment-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

You can run `heroku buildpacks:clear -a yourAppName` and redeploy the app.